# Saved web pages when opened shows nothing

Tags: python, html, save, web-crawler

I'm using `python` to crawl a webpage and save it. And the code works properly. But when I open the web page it just shows the website name i.e., **http://www.indiabix.com** and not the actual content.

You can just go the website and save one of it's pages **NOT** the homepage but other pages like **http://www.indiabix.com/database/questions-and-answers/**. And when you open it, the page just shows this

[image]

and not this

[image]

The code I've written is simple

```
def writeToFile(link, name, title):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    webContent = response.read()
    f = open(name + '/' + title, 'w')
    f.write(webContent)
    f.close
```

You just pass the link, directory name and title of file.

I have checked in Chrome, Firefox and Safari and all show the same output. How can I resolve this issue to display the entire saved page fully.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the Javascript in your browser and open it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify something like this. [Install](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/) `requests`.

```
import os
import requests

def write_to_file(link, name, title):
    with open(os.path.join(name, title), "w") as fp: 
        fp.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

Comment: I tried running the code but it shows the same output. Did you try running the code with the same url I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yep. Disable the Javascript in your browser and open it or try to open with a text editor.

Comment: Yes, disabling javascript and saving the webpage then opening it worked. Thank you very much. But I lose all the css while saving from the script you provided and mine too. What about that?

Comment: We are downloading the HTML only using our program and it won't pull any of the JavaScript/Images/CSS files included in the page. You can try using some scrapping frameworks like `scrapy`. What is your use case here?

Comment: I need to save these pages for offline use. I don't get internet all the times

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can do an experiment by right-clicking the webpage and save the complete web files. And then use your browser to open the `.htm` file, you will get the same result. And when you inspect the page you can see there are some errors(files not found). So I think there are some errors within this webpage.

[image]

Comment: I right clicked on the webpage and saved it. I open the .html file, it shows only the website name. I can see the errors when inspecting but how should I save the webpage so that I can access them when I've no Internet?

Comment: you should check the code in `.htm`, if there are something need to fetch by internet then it's not possible